# When I click checkbox on a list of items and delete them not all of them are removed, but when I only check off one it works fine. Why?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

When I click a checkbox and click delete on a single item in the list it deletes as expected. When I check all items and click delete it does not. I do not know why and I would like to know. I understand that in order to remove elements in the array in reference to a DOM element index you must first get the DOM elements index, but I am not interested in that at the moment. I really just have no idea why this code doesn't work and it makes me feel stupid.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let toDos = [
     { title: "MOM", complete: false }
    ,{ title: "DAD", complete: false }
    ,{ title: "The Universe", complete: false }
    ,{ title: "MOM", complete: false }
    ,{ title: "DAD", complete: false }
    ,{ title: "The Universe", complete: false}
  ];

  const deleteButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  var inputElems = document.querySelectorAll(".todo-delete");

  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    inputElems = document.querySelectorAll(".todo-delete");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i += 1) {
      if (inputElems[i].checked) {
        toDos = toDos.filter(function(val, index) {
          if (index !== i) {
            return val
          }
        });
      }
    }

    inputElems = document.querySelectorAll(".todo-delete");
    console.log(toDos);
    renderDOM(toDos);
  });

  function renderDOM(toDos) {
    const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');

    todoList.textContent = '';

    toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {
      const newLi = document.createElement('li');
      const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
      checkbox.className = "todo-delete";
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";

      newLi.textContent = toDo.title;

      todoList.appendChild(newLi);
      newLi.appendChild(checkbox);
    });
  }

  renderDOM(toDos)
};
```

```html
<ul id="todo-list">
</ul>
<hr>
<button>delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you filter `toDos` array. Your for loop index `i` becomes more than there are elements in `toDos` array after you filter more than half of `toDos` content in one operation.

Change `for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i += 1) {`
to `for (var i = inputElems.length -1; i >= 0; i--)`

Here we change the loop directiom from going left to right we are going right to left, meaning decreasing index each iteration, so when we filter out 1 element we also decrease the `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you filter your array after each delete and the indexes get changed. You need to know all the indexes to delete before you actually delete them.

```
window.onload = function() {
    let
    toDos = [ {
        title : "MOM",
        complete : false
    }, {
        title : "DAD",
        complete : false
    }, {
        title : "The Universe",
        complete : false
    }, {
        title : "MOM",
        complete : false
    }, {
        title : "DAD",
        complete : false
    }, {
        title : "The Universe",
        complete : false
    } ];

    const deleteButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    var inputElems = document.querySelectorAll(".todo-delete");

    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        inputElems = document.querySelectorAll(".todo-delete");

        var removes = []; // added this part
        for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i += 1) {
            if (inputElems[i].checked) {
                removes.push(i); // added this part
            }
        }

        toDos = toDos.filter(function(val, index) {
            if (removes.indexOf(index) === -1) { // added this part
                return val;
            }
        });

        inputElems = document.querySelectorAll(".todo-delete");
        renderDOM(toDos);
    });

    function renderDOM(toDos) {
        const
        todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');

        todoList.textContent = '';

        toDos.forEach(function(toDo) {
            const
            newLi = document.createElement('li');
            const
            checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.className = "todo-delete";
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";

            newLi.textContent = toDo.title;

            todoList.appendChild(newLi);
            newLi.appendChild(checkbox);
        });
    }

    renderDOM(toDos)
};
```